# Como listar dados de um banco Mysql usando o método List do java (jdbc)?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, eclipse, jdbc

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar listar os dados.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at modelo.Dao.getLista(Dao.java:111) at principal.Main.listarViagem(Main.java:161) at principal.Main.menu(Main.java:58) at principal.Main.main(Main.java:39)

Meus códigos:

#### ClasseDAO

```
 public List<Bean> getLista() {
     try {
         List<Bean> viagens = new ArrayList<Bean>();
 
         PreparedStatement stmt = ConexaoMySQL.
                 prepareStatement("select * from viagem");
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
 
         while (rs.next()) {
             // criando o objeto viagem
             Bean viagem = new Bean();
             viagem.setIdViagem(rs.getInt("idViagem"));
             
             Calendar dataInicio = Calendar.getInstance();
             dataInicio.setTime(rs.getDate("dataInicio"));
             viagem.setDataInicio(dataInicio);
             
             Calendar dataF = Calendar.getInstance();
             dataF.setTime(rs.getDate("dataFim"));
             viagem.setDataFim(dataF);
             
             viagem.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
             viagem.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
             viagem.setValorDiaria(rs.getDouble("valorDiaria"));
             viagem.setColaborador(rs.getString("colaborador"));
             viagem.setCliente(rs.getString("cliente"));
 
             // adicionando o objeto à lista
             viagens.add(viagem);
         }
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         return viagens;
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
   }
 }
```

#### Classe Main

```
private static void listarViagem() {
    Dao dao = new Dao();
            
    List<Bean> viagens = dao.getLista();
            
    for (Bean contato : viagens) {
        System.out.println("IdViagem: " + contato.getIdViagem());
        System.out.println("tipo: " + contato.getTipo());
        System.out.println("Data de inicio: " + 
                              contato.getDataInicio().getTime() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Data de fim: " + 
                          contato.getDataFim().getTime() + "\n");
        System.out.println("cidade: " + contato.getCidade());
        System.out.println("uf: " + contato.getUf());
        System.out.println("valor da diaria: " + contato.getValorDiaria());
        System.out.println("colaborador: " + contato.getColaborador());
        System.out.println("cliente: " + contato.getCliente());
    
    
    }    
}
```

Existe alguma maneira mais simplifica de fazer a listagem dos dados   usando o jdbc em java ? Qual a forma mais simples de se fazer isso?

Comment: Está dando algum erro?

Comment: pro seu código no main e no DAO ficarem mais simples, você pode criar um construtor do Bean passando o resultset como parametro pra setar os atributos, e pode tambem sobrescrever o metodo toString, que ali seu for seria só System.out.println(contato)

Comment: Pelo console tá dando um erro no método getLista.

Comment: Poste sua StackTrace @Jarwin

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at modelo.Dao.getLista(Dao.java:111)
 at principal.Main.listarViagem(Main.java:161)
 at principal.Main.menu(Main.java:58)
 at principal.Main.main(Main.java:39)

Comment: Só queria um método em List que listasse os meus dados para completar o meu CRUD '-'

Comment: E qual linha seria a 111 do DAO?

Comment: ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

Comment: como está implementando o ConexaoMySQL?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eVsmD2JR

Comment: @Jarwin o seu método `prepareStatement("select * from viagem");` retorna `null` por isso há exceção quando tentar executar `stmt.executeQuery();`

Comment: O compilador manda eu criar um método prepareStatement na minha classe conexãomysql, tem outra maneira de se fazer o meu método no dao ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solução do meu problema:***

Eu tinha que setar a minha ConexaoMySQL antes do PreparedStatement por isso que dava dando erro. Agora compilou :-)

> ```
> ConexaoMySQL.conectar();
>
>           PreparedStatement stmt = ConexaoMySQL.getConexao()
>                   .prepareStatement("select * from viagem ");
> ```